# add string when checkbox ischecked

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I have checkboxes on a page. What I am trying to do is when the user is clicking on the checkbox, its value would be printed below the table. Multiple values can be printed in line, separated by ',':
Like this

> a,b,c,d

```js
function gant(id) {
  var arr = []
  $('#pil_' + id).each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      arr.push($(this).val())
    }
  })
  var vals = arr.join("+");
  var str = vals;
  $("#val").text(str);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" id="pil_1" onchange="gant(1)" value="a" />a</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" id="pil_2" onchange="gant(2)" value="b"/>b</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" id="pil_3" onchange="gant(3)" value="c" />c</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" id="pil_4" onchange="gant(4)" value="d"/>d</label>
<div id="val"></div>
```

but it's just showing only a or b or c or d

Answer (score 2):

There will only be one id passed into the function so loop over the class instead.

```
$('.offers:checked').each(function(){
     arr.push($(this).val());          
})
```

Comment: Why ...is it not working? Is a very minor change to test it yourself

Answer (score 0):

The below should work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function gant(id) {

var arr = [];
  $(':checkbox[name="selected"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        arr.push($(this).val())
    }

  })
  //alert(arr);
  var vals = arr.join(",");
  var str = vals ;
  $("#val").text(str);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" id="pil_1" onchange="gant(1)" value="a" />a</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" id="pil_2" onchange="gant(2)" value="b"/>b</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" id="pil_3" onchange="gant(3)" value="c" />c</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" id="pil_4" onchange="gant(4)" value="d"/>d</label>
<div id="val"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change id selector to class like this:

```js
function gant(id){
            var arr = [];
            $('.offers').each(function(){
                if($(this).is(":checked")){
                    arr.push($(this).val())
                }
            })
            var vals = arr.join(",");
            var str = vals;
            $("#val").text(str);
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="selected1" id="pil_1" onChange="gant(1)" value="a" class="offers" />a</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="selected2" id="pil_2" onChange="gant(2)" value="b" class="offers" />b</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="selected3" id="pil_3" onChange="gant(3)" value="c" class="offers" />c</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="selected4" id="pil_4" onChange="gant(4)" value="d" class="offers" />d</label>
        <br>
        <label id="val"></label>
```